# want to put logo centre of the page between two lines

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to make a grid-like **5.5-1-5.5**. Is it possible because I want to put that logo in the center of the page and two lines on the left & right?
(my English is not good)

[image]

Comment: you can't make grid as `5.5-1-5.5` but you can make one as `5-2-5`

Comment: I want line side by side with little bit distance and logo should be small in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex` and pseudos will do :

```css
.lines {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.lines:before,
.lines:after {
  content: '';
  border: 4px solid black;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  margin: 0 1em;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lines"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150&text=logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a background like so?

```css
.background{
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/kBiG6ql.png') center repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img class="logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/h4J7ZvW.png"/>
</div>
```